# I'm trying to add % to cell values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains list item in a column.

```
column1, column2 
1         1       
2         None    
3         2
```

so I want to append '%' values to column2 where the values are present.

Expected output:

```
column1, column2 
1         1%     
2         None     
3         2%
```

I've tried below method.

```
df['column2'] += '%'
```

but i'm getting this error cannot brodcst np.ndarray with operand oftype<class 'list'>

I'm new to pandas please guide me.

Comment: What is `df.to_dict()` ?

Comment: What is the `dtype` of `column2`? In order to add a `%`, this must be `str`, not `int` or `double`.